# Convert Document Library from Classic to Modern

Tags: document-library, modern-experience, classic-experience, modern-document-library

I have inherited a SharePoint site that was initially created in the Classic SharePoint format. I am in the process of changing everything over to the Modern SharePoint version but there is one library that is stubborn and I cannot change from Classic to Modern.

I have gone to the Library Settings -> Advanced Settings and changed the following...
[image: List Experience]

But my Library still displays like this.
[image: Classic Library]

I have also tried to change the Library view, and I initially had it setup properly but in deleting the old views to prevent the Classic interface, I cannot seem to get the proper Modern view back.

I also have clicked on the Exit classic experience button on the library page and besides refreshing the page, it does not do anything.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am unable to convert classic library to modern. When I add ?Contents=1 to the url I don't see content editor webpart but it has script editor webarts. Can I delete them to convert classic to modern library?
What would be the solution?
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm5nR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm5nR.png)

Comment: @Apoorva, sorry, I do not know if that would fix your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite some time with my company's IT department, they were able to identify how to resolve this issue for me. Unfortunately you cannot get to these settings by clicking through the front end. You need to navigate to the Library and then add `?Contents=1` to the end of the URL. Once there, I had to delete these 2 WebParts.
[image]

I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Thank you so much - I've spent days working on this issue and opening every single site setting I could find to no avail. Your answer was the only one that worked :)